# Generator in Python only returning first element

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to create a generator in python 3.4 using the built in next() function. Here is my current code:

```
myGenerator = next(t for t in [1,2,3,4])
myGenerator
1
myGenerator
1.....
```

Whenever I call the generator I built, it only returns 1 each time I call it, which is strange, as I thought that each element in the generator can only be iterated through once. How do I fix this code, so that it will print out 1,2,3,4, in that order? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `next` is not how you build a generator - it's how you retrieve elements from it... Your code is effectively `myGenerator = 1`

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit nice, because you actually have the generator which you want, which is

```
(t for t in [1,2,3,4])
```

but then you run `next` on it. If you look at [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) you can see that it's doing exactly what the docs say: you applied `next` to the generator, it returned an object, and you bound this object to something you called `myGenerator` (it's probably yours, but it's not a generator). Each time you call it, it evaluates to a simple object.

```
>>> myGenerator = (t for t in [1,2,3,4])
>>> print next(myGenerator)
1
>>> print next(myGenerator)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to use `next`, I suggest you use `yield`:

```
def g(l):
    for i,x in enumerate(l):
        yield x
        if i == len(l):
            break

for i in g([1,2,3,4]):
    print i
```

Demo:

```
1
2
3
4
```

`yield` can do same feature.